# Filename when downloading APK on Android

Tags: android, .htaccess, download, apk

When I download a file on my Android phone from my webserver it save it as

```
 downloadfile.apk
```

The file is saved on my server as MyApp.apk

Do you know how to make the file appear as MyApp.apk in the downloaded files list on Android?

I should also mention that to get the file to download and be understood by the phone I modified the .htaccess file on the server to be

```
 AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive apk
 DirectoryIndex MyApp.apk
```

Comment: are you downloading your file via http browser???

Comment: yes - the user would click on a link and have the file downloaded to there phone

Comment: Why are you using `DirectoryIndex` instead of just linking to the file directly (I assume you're linking to a directory now)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it to work on my server by adding this to my .htaccess

```
AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive apk
```

You shouldn't have put the 2nd line in yours. Also, make sure you have a line break at the very end, I have had issues before when missing that.